# Type bounds on functions

Tags: scala, types

I am having trouble getting my code with parameterized types to pass the scala compiler. My goal is to be able to express `(Predicate, Action)` pairs as shown in the `MyProg` object.

```
trait ProgBase {
  type Predicate[T] = T => Boolean
  type Action[T]    = T => Unit

  private var prog = List[(Predicate[Any], Action[Any])]()

  final def on[T <: Any](pred: Predicate[T])(action: Action[T]) = {
    prog = (pred, action) :: prog // gives type mismatch
  }

  // remainder of trait elided
}

object MyProg extends ProgBase {
  on[String](s => !s.isEmpty) { s =>
    println(s + " is not empty")
  }

  on[Int](i => i.isValidByte) { i =>
    println(i + " can fit in a byte")
  }
}
```

By specifying that `T` has an upper bound of `Any`, I hoped this would appease the compiler, but clearly I am missing something:

```
[error] ......ProgBase.scala:8 type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (T => Boolean, T => Unit)
[error]  required: (Any => Boolean, Any => Unit)
[error]     prog = (pred, action) :: prog
[error]                           ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, answer to your question, if you write:

```
private var prog = List[(Predicate[_ <: Any], Action[_ <: Any])]()
```

It all compiles OK. We should use wildcards, 'cause the type of elements are unknown.

Second, maybe you mistyped, you can't use your `on` function as you used it, use it something like:

```
on[String](s => !s.isEmpty)(s => !s.isEmpty)
```

It caused by type mismatch: `type Action[T] = T => Unit` but `println` has type `Unit`,
so as a variant u can simply write: `type Action = Unit`. Obviously, u can avoid using this type alias at all.

Third, maybe you already know, and I shoudn't tell you, that in fact, you lose all information about predicate types - let's check it using Scala reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
def getTypeTag[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: T) = ru.typeTag[T]

val s: String = "123" 
val i: Int = 123

on[String](s => !s.isEmpty)(s => !s.isEmpty)
on[Int](i => i.isValidByte)(i => i.isValidByte)

getTypeTag((MyProg.prog.head._1)).tpe =:= ru.typeOf[(String) => Boolean] //>false!
```

So you see the problem.

To deal with it you can use heterogeneous lists. Lists and other various powerful structures you can find in shapeless: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Comment: The wildcard tip was perfect! Yes, I mistyped the body of the Actions, will fix. And THANKS for heads up on the third issue, which I guess is due to type erasure. Will look at shapeless.

Comment: I want to add, that it is not necessary to use `<: Any`, 'cause `Any` is a super type of all types. But, it seems to me u know it.